# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la clave primaria de mi tabla mediante Oracle Database Change Notification?

Tags: java, oracle

He podido recibir notificaciones de una base de datos en Oracle gracias a [este código](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35106563/111110) y omitiendo esta línea:

```
prop.setProperty(OracleConnection.DCN_QUERY_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION,"true");
```

También pude resolver mi problema ORA-29977 cambiando `select * from act_code_metadata where product_id=1159` por `select column_with_Number_type from act_code_metadata where product_id=1159`

Todo funciona como lo esperado :D

Éste es el código que uso para imprimir la información de la fila (Java 8):

```
DatabaseChangeRegistration dcp.addListener((DatabaseChangeEvent dce) -> 
                System.out.println(
                "Changed row id : " +
                dce.getTableChangeDescription()[0].getRowChangeDescription()[0].getRowid().stringValue() 
                + " " +  dce.getTableChangeDescription()[0].getRowChangeDescription()[0].getRowOperation().toString()));
```

Pero toda la información que obtengo es la dirección física de la fila (rowid) y la operación implicada (insert, delete o update).
Necesito identificar la fila que se está modificando/insertando/eliminando para refrescar mi data en caché en varios controles de Swing de mi GUI.

[He leído que](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:53140678334596), [a pesar de que el rowid es inmutable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11586285/111110), el mismo rowid puede ser re-asignado si la fila es borrada y una nueva es insertada, y que el rowid puede cambiar si la fila está en una tabla particionada. De modo que lo mejor que puedo hacer es usar el rowid y la clave primaria de la fila. 
Mi tabla tiene una clave primaria autoincrementable (con una secuencia y un trigger) creada con [este código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11296471/111110).

No tengo control sobre lo que sucede en la basse de datos o si alguien inserta y elimina filas varias veces. De modo que puedo obtener la fila equivocada al seleccionarla usando el rowid dado por la notificación.

¿Hay alguna manera de obtener la clave primaria via Oracle Database Change Notification de manera que puedo identificar la fila insertada/eliminada/modificada correctamente?

Estoy trabajando con Oracle Database XE 11.2 Express y Java 8. El usuario que se usa para las notificaciones ya tiene privilegio change notification: `grant change notification to the_user;`

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es escontrar el object_id de tu row_id

```
SELECT DBMS_ROWID.ROWID_OBJECT('TU_ROW_ID') FROM DUAL;
```

Despues busca la tabla a la que pertene ese id

```
SELECT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME 
FROM ALL_OBJECTS 
WHERE OBJECT_ID = TU_OBJECT_ID
```

Si lo prefieres en una sola consulta

```
SELECT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME 
FROM ALL_OBJECTS 
WHERE OBJECT_ID = (SELECT DBMS_ROWID.ROWID_OBJECT('TU_ROW_ID') FROM DUAL)
```

Ya tienes el owner y la tabla asi que solo hace falta ejecutar la query para encontrar la PK

```
SELECT COLS.COLUMN_NAME
FROM ALL_CONSTRAINTS CONS, ALL_CONS_COLUMNS COLS
WHERE COLS.TABLE_NAME = 'OBJECT_NAME'
AND COLS.OWNER = 'OWNER'
AND CONS.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'P'
AND CONS.CONSTRAINT_NAME = COLS.CONSTRAINT_NAME
AND CONS.OWNER = COLS.OWNER
ORDER BY COLS.TABLE_NAME, COLS.POSITION;
```